# How to - When image is clicked set opacity to 1 and lower opacity for other images

Tags: javascript, arrays, image-gallery

I couldn't for the life of me figure this out! How can I make this happen -  When image is clicked set opacity to 1 and lower opacity for other images? I was told to add a class to the clicked image, store it, then remove the class when another image is clicked? but i cant figure it out!

```js
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const el = event.target;
for(var i=0; i< smallImg.length; i++) { 
  if (el.className !== 'sec') return;
  const wasSelected = el.classList.contains('selected');
  for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div >img'))
    d.classList.remove('selected');
  el.classList.toggle('selected', !wasSelected)
  console.log(".selected");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.sec:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.sec:not:active{
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
          <img
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?stationery"
            class="item main-image"
          />
          <div class="secondary-image">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pen"
              class="item sec item-1 active "
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pencil"
              class="item sec item-2"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?notepad"
              class="item sec item-3"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?eraser"
              class="item sec item-4"
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure `img` can have a state of `active`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that as well, but the opacity only remains for the moment image is clicked.

Comment: `.sec:not:active` makes no sense, that is not even valid CSS. Do you want to apply the changing opacity only to the images within `<div class="secondary-image">` here, or is the big, "main" one also included?

Comment: @CBroe main image not included! you can ignore the CSS for now, that's only for the styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the element that currently has the `active` class, and if such an element exists, remove that class from that. And then add it to the one that was clicked.

(Any check on whether the clicked element was actually one of those images, is not currently included. I simply kept your general click handler for `body`, please refine this yourself to apply only where needed.)

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let el = event.target;
  let prev = document.querySelector('.secondary-image .active');
  if(prev) {
    prev.classList.remove('active');
  }
  el.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.secondary-image .sec:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
          <img
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?stationery"
            class="item main-image"
          />
          <div class="secondary-image">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pen"
              class="item sec item-1 active "
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?pencil"
              class="item sec item-2"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?notepad"
              class="item sec item-3"
            />
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100/?eraser"
              class="item sec item-4"
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh! one quick question - this CSS code that you added .sec:not(.active) - is it gathering the elements with class of 'sec' and does NOT have a class 'active'?

Comment: Yes, `:not()` can exclude elements from the selection based on specific criteria. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: You could probably also do away with the `sec` class completely here, and simply select the images based on that they are inside `.secondary-image` - `.secondary-image img:not(.active)`, or `.secondary-image .item:not(.active)` (the latter perhaps if you had other image elements within the same container, that should not get affected.)

Comment: I also noticed that when i click outside the thumbnail image group, all the images turn to have opacity 0.3, any way to set the opacity for the first thumbnail to be 1 IF WE CLICK ANYWHERE outside the image group? should we add a 'else if' statement?

Comment: I think I figured it out! Added this snippet:
  if(!el.classList.contains('sec')){
  prev.classList.add("active")}